# Conversão de valor tido Date no sqlite Android error The method getText() is undefined for the type String

Tags: android, sqlite

Estou fazendo a inserção de um valor tipo DATE no meu projeto, para isso tive que converte-lo, na minha classe correspondente, meu tributo Dt_leitura, está declarada como string e no banco ela está como Date.
Para isso, no momento em que estou inserindo o registro no banco, estou convertendo ele, da forma abaixo:

```
public Consumo inserir (Consumo consumo){

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dateFormat.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date data =  (Date) dateFormat.parse(consumo.dt_leitura.getText());  


        ContentValues valores = new ContentValues();

        valores.put("dt_leitura",dateFormat.format(data));  
        valores.put("registro", consumo.getRegistro());

        consumo.setId(db.insert("consumo", null, valores ));
        return consumo;


}
```

Só que no trecho

```
Date data =  (Date) dateFormat.parse(consumo.dt_leitura.getText());
```

esta retornando o seguinte erro:

> The method getText() is undefined for the type String

Saberiam me dizer se estou também fazendo a conversão correta da data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro diz que a classe String não tem nenhum método com o nome *getText*

O método `parse()` da classe *SimpleDateFormat* recebe uma String, tal como você diz na pergunta, o atributo `consumo.dt_leitura` é uma String, portanto passe-o directamente ao método `parse()`:

```
Date data =  (Date) dateFormat.parse(consumo.dt_leitura);
```

Comment: Ola ramal, Obrigado pela atenção e resposta
Infelizmente após eu alterar da forma que me mostrou
 Date data =  (Date) dateFormat.parse(consumo.dt_leitura);  
 ainda me retorna o erro Unhandled exception type ParseException, saberia me dizer o motivo ?

Comment: Sem saber o que `consumo.dt_leitura` retorna/contém não.

Comment: Amaral,deu certo da forma que me passou, na verdade esse erro que citei acima, a aplicação só estava informado que precisava de um try catch, coloquei e funcionou.
obrigado